# Oracle SQL join performance strangely low

Tags: sql, oracle, join, execution-time

I have a SQL statement like following:

```
SELECT {SOME CASE WHEN STATEMENTS}
FROM {SUBQUERY 1} A, {SUBQUERY 2} B
WHERE {SOME JOIN CONDITIONS}
```

Background:

- Both subquery A and B can be executed in 15 seconds and returns fewer than 20 rows.
- JOIN CONDITIONS are only three simple common fields bind together.
- Execution plan looks fine, only 25 costs.

The problem in that the whole join operation takes 4 to 5 minutes to run.

Could anyone tell me any possibility to cause this?

Comment: Definitely missing indexes, or subqueries that prevent use of indexes. But it is impossible to say which without seeing table, index definitions and real query.

Comment: Did you maybe forget the *actual* join - as you are using old-style (SQL '89) implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause this is easy to forget and you'll get a cartesian product. What happens when you use the modern explicit `JOIN`s? Also what does the execution plan say?

Comment: We really can't tell for sure without seeing an actual query and actual table and index definitions.

Comment: i would look at A and B since they seem slow to begin with.  check the explain plan for full table scans.

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name, I would suspect a cross join due to using implicit joins. Unless you use a very old version of ORacle, you need to stop using them altogether. They create issues exactly like this (A cross join and then using a distinct to clear out the dups often happens and is very costly). You could also check indexes on your join fields. Sometimes people forget to index the FK fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NO_PUSH_PRED Hint:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABGJBJC

Alternatively try to rewrite the query into something like:

```
SELECT {SOME CASE WHEN STATEMENTS}
FROM ( 
    SELECT * FROM (
         { SUBQUERY 1}
    )
    WHERE rownum > 0
) A, 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        {SUBQUERY 2}
    ) 
    WHERE rownum > 0
) B
WHERE {SOME JOIN CONDITIONS}
```

this will prevent from pusing join predcates into  nested subqueries.
Then both subqueries should be executed using "old" plans, and the total time should be 15+15 seconds + a small time to join 40 rows from both subqueries.